# How to return a excel file back to a user using Django and Pandas

Tags: python, django, pandas

I am currently taking an excel file from the user on my home.html page, passing it to my python, using the values to do some logic, and wanting to returned a excel file back to the user after the logic has edited the data. I had this working as an .exe on my computer already but wanted to move it to a web page. I am not currently getting any errors. Does anyone know how to do this, or know of a walkthrough that might can help me?

```
def page_objects(request):
    Area = request.POST["Area"]
    Output = request.POST["Output"]
    FilePath = request.FILES['myfile']
    if Output == 'List':
        zone = pd.read_excel(FilePath, sheet_name= "Form", header=0, usecols=list(range(7)))
        WC = zone.iat[3,4]
        data = pd.read_excel(FilePath, sheet_name="Form", header=0, usecols=list(range(7)), skiprows=8) 
        data2= pd.read_excel(FilePath, sheet_name="Form", header=0, usecols=list(range(7)), skiprows=8)
```

Then I do some logic

```
        writer = ExcelWriter(FilePath)
        data.to_excel(writer, 'Sheet1', index=False)
        data2.to_excel(writer, 'Sheet2', index=False)
    
        writer.save()
    return render(request, 'home.html')
```

When I was using the .exe ExcelWriter("location where I saved the new file") was how I returned the edited data to myself.

Edit 1:

I have adjusted the code to

```
        io = StringIO()

        writer = ExcelWriter(io)


        data.to_excel(writer, 'Sheet1', index=False)
        data2.to_excel(writer, 'Sheet2', index=False)
        response = HttpResponse(io.getvalue(), content_type='application/zip')
        response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=myfile.zip'
    return render(response, 'home.html')
```

I am now getting the error 'HttpResponse' object has no attribute 'META' not sure how to resolve this.

Edit 2:
it seems I might be able to solve this by using writer.save(response) however I am getting the error "save() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given" and I am not sure how to solve this.

```
        io = StringIO()

        writer = ExcelWriter(io)


        data.to_excel(writer, 'Sheet1', index=False)
        data2.to_excel(writer, 'Sheet2', index=False)
        writer.save(response)
```

Edit 3:

I am not longer having any errors appears, however the file is not getting returned to the html page. This is my current code without errors.

```
from IO import *
        io = BytesIO()

        writer = ExcelWriter(io)


        data.to_excel(writer, 'Sheet1', index=False)
        data2.to_excel(writer, 'Sheet2', index=False)
        writer.save()
        rFile = io.getvalue()
        response = HttpResponse(rFile,content_type='application/ms-excel')
        response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=temp.xls'
    return render(request, 'home.html')
```

Going to keep working on how to return the file to the page.

Edit 4:

I was able to solve this issue. Below is the code I needed to return the excel file.

```
        io = BytesIO()

        writer = ExcelWriter(io)


        data.to_excel(writer, 'Sheet1', index=False)
        data2.to_excel(writer, 'Sheet2', index=False)
        writer.save()
        rFile = io.getvalue()
        response = HttpResponse(rFile ,content_type='application/ms-excel')
        response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=temp.xls'
        return response
    return render(request, 'home.html')
```

Comment: I think that FileResponse() might be the answer to my question. Attempting to play around with request = FileResponse(open(writer)) .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I answered this question in edit 4 of my post.